# Roots of a polynomial depending analytically on a parameter.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Prove that the equation

$$ z^3+wz+w=0 $$

admits three roots depending analytically on the parameter $w$, in the disk $|w-1|=1$.

I understand that the equation has three roots and these roots will depend on $w$. But I am not sure what it means to say "depending analytically on the parameter $w$, in the disk $|w-1|=1$."

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A root is an analytic function of $w$ as long as it is not multiple, i.e., is not shared by the polynomial and its $z$-derivative. So try to show that this polynomial and its derivartive, $3z^2+w$, do not have common roots whenever $w$ lies in the disk. By the way, you apparently meant $|w-1|<1$.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for your response. That makes sense.